# running several commands using php's shell_exec

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I've tried for a while now every way possibly known to me, and have yet to crack this thing, it's probably very trivial but couldn't find the answer.

I want to run several commands at once using php shell_exec,
for example `shell_exec("cd ..; dir")`
but I am unable to find how to execute a few commands, what is the seperator? is it ;, is it /n? nothing seems to work.

Please note I am running with windows.

Comment: On Unix, you can separate commands with `;`; not sure about Windows. That said, what's wrong with doing multiple `shell_exec()` calls? Much easier to debug, too.

Comment: @Pekka , each shell exec launches a new `instance` of shell, so they're missing the context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://superuser.com/a/62854

> `&&` will execute command 2 when command 1 is complete providing it
>   didn't fail, `&` will execute regardless.